# Can you auto-Import variables when you import functions in python

Tags: python, python-import

So I have a function from a module to be imported.
But I want the import to perform some other actions like some initializing.

for example

```
#this is the_mod.py
name1 = 'Bob'
name2 = 'Alice'

def fun1(x):
    #some action

def fun2(y):
    #some action
```

```
#the external script
from the_mod.py import fun1
fun1(name1)
```

I want to access `name1` and `name2` from `the_mod.py` but is there anyway to import it automatically when I import any of it's functions?

Comment: Bad idea - that would hide the origin of the names, without even any indication that anything weird is happening in those imports, and importing variables misbehaves enough already (due to how it creates new variables instead of using the originals) without piling additional magic on top.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `from` in python imports, you specifically choose what to import. So you would need to include your variable:

```py
#the external script
from the_mod.py import fun1, name1
fun1(name1)
```

Alternatively, and not often a good idea, you can use `*` which imports everything:

```py
#the external script
from the_mod.py import *
fun1(name1)
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to do so u must declare the variables inside the `def`
Like

```
#THIS IS the_mod.py
def fun1 (x):
    name1='Bob'
    name2='Alice'
    #some action
```

Otherwise do it as Keldan Chapman does, like everyone does

Comment: I am not doing this in greed of upvotes or reputation so i don't care if anyone downvotes. Just wanted to help you and posted a completely selfless answer....

Comment: Importing `fun1` will not import `name1` with this code, and calls like `fun1(name1)` will fail.

Comment: I did not say anything about the action he wants to do. Alright i am also adding the external script.